# Data migration from MapR to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hive, hbase, mapr

How can we migrate on-premise data to Amazon s3.

1) MaprDB binary table data migration to AWS Hbase.
2) Hive data migration to AWS Hive tables.

Should we use S3DistCp or AWS DataSync Or there are some other way for the same.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-3x-s3distcp.html

Answer (score 0):

the best option as of now from AWS side to explore more on DataSync if you are doing online data migration.